# Why bootstrap-select fires several times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap was firing several times (two times in my case).

I solved this using:

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

Why does Bootstrap select fire several times?

```
<p>
    <?php 
    for ($i = 2013; $i < 2016; $i++) { ?>
        <select class="selectpicker mySelector" id="mySelector<?php echo $i?>" multiple style="color:white;">
          <option value="general">Grafica general</option>
          <option value="all">Todas las graficas</option>

        </select>
    <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('change', '.mySelector', function(e) {
                alert('hello world!');
                e.stopPropagation();

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML ?

Comment: This code is included in a form ? I mean the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple `select` items with class `.mySelector` so event is fired multiple times.